# Easy way for client to add photos to a photo gallery himself? Any simple non-CMS methods?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, photo-gallery

I'm building a website for a client and there is a page that will contain a photo gallery of around 10-20 photos. I was planning to have the client email me new photos to add to the gallery as the need arises (probably will only happen 2x a year). HOWEVER, my boss is demanding I develop some kind of method that will allow the client to easily add photos himself. Perhaps an XML method or something. Aside from a full-blown CMS, what is a very simple way for the client to add photos himself without having to rely on me to do it for him? In case this matters, I'm using Bootstrap 3 and JQuery. Any good simple solutions out there? How would YOU do it?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow as it's very general, but - you're likely to need a server-side programming language for this, and these things tend to get out of hand when built from scratch. There are readymade PHP products that you may want to look at. e.g. http://www.design3edge.com/2010/08/26/best-free-and-open-source-php-image-galleries/

Comment: Yes, you’re gonna need a server side language to handle the upload.  I could tell you how to write it in PHP but I think you’re talking about a lot of hours to get it tested and working perfectly.

Comment: What is your server-side language?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid server side scripting, you can do this very simply with the Google Fusion Tables API.  You populate the gallery from the API JSON output, and your client can manage the images by adding/deleting/amending the file names, etc. in the FT.  The images can be hosted anywhere online - Flickr, your web server, the client's site.